# AngularJS: Setting filtered object property value doesn't update automatically on change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array on the scope that is being used to populate an ng-repeat with checkboxes inside.

I have a property in an object that I'm trying to set to contain that array filtered by checkboxes in the ng-repeat that have been checked.

Basic HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="box in boxes"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="box.checked" ng-click="testingOnly()"/> {{box.label}}</li>
    </ul>
    <div ng-repeat="object in objects.prop1">{{object.label}}</div>
    <div ng-repeat="object in objects.prop2">{{object.label}}</div>
</div>
```

Basic JS:

```
function MyCtrl($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.boxes = [{label: 'Mon'}, {label: 'Tue'}, {label: 'Wed'}, {label: 'Thu'}, {label: 'Fri'}, {label: 'Sat'}, {label: 'Sun'}];

    $scope.objects = {
        prop1: [{label: 'You have chosen the following days:'}],
        prop2: $filter('filter')($scope.boxes, {checked: true})
    }

    $scope.testingOnly = function() {
     $scope.objects.prop2 = $filter('filter')($scope.boxes, {checked: true});
    }
}
```

JSFiddle: [http://jsfiddle.net/97ton8ua/5/](http://jsfiddle.net/97ton8ua/1/)

I think I'm not understanding some fundamental part of how Angular is working. I was hoping to wire the two pieces together and that **objects.prop2** would update without writing any additional helper function.

Is it possible to accomplish that (via model attachments/something in the markup/etc...), or will I have to keep the helper function to run every time the checkbox is clicked?

Comment: I think the function-way is the way to go. Another option is to deep `$watch` for changes in `boxes`, but it would be unnecessarily taxing

Comment: Yah, I think the function will do for now. I've been trying to avoid things like $watch the way I've been trying to avoid jQuery...seems better to avoid it when still trying to understand the basics :D

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you go about it this way and use two way binding, way easier and cleaner I think: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/97ton8ua/3/)

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="box in boxes">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selection.value" ng-true-value="{{box.label}}" ng-false-value="" />{{box.label}}</li>


    </ul>
        <div ng-repeat="object in objects.prop1">{{object.label}}</div>{{selection.value}}

</div>

</div>
```

Angular

```
angular.module('myApp', [])

.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';
    $scope.boxes = [{
        label: 'something else'
    }, {
        label: 'world'
    }]; 
    $scope.selection = {};
    $scope.objects = {
        prop1: [{
            label: 'hello'
        }]
    };

});
```

Comment: Hmm, if I understand the way this is working I don't think it will be appropriate for my case. I need to return multiple potential selections, but yours functions more like a radio button where {{selection.value}} will only ever be one thing. Here's an updated fiddle with a more detailed idea of what I'm doing: [http://jsfiddle.net/97ton8ua/5/](http://jsfiddle.net/97ton8ua/5/)